# Excel convert dates from different formats

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, date-formatting

I have a data set with column `A` containing different date formats, the column format is `date`:

[image]

I would like to have all entries in the format `dd-mm-yyyy`, and one formula for the whole column.

With *format cells*, I could not get them into the same format.
I tried `TEXT(A3, "dd-mm-yyyy")`, but this does not do anything. 
`DATEVALUE(A3)` gives me an error. 
Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: how to understand in wich format this date: 01-02-1973 is it 01 feb or 02 jan?

Comment: Earliest date Excel can handle and calculate with is 01-01-1900, so 1885 is NOT possible. Later date values can simply be conevrted by `DATEVALUE()`.

Comment: @Asger: Aah, I see, with for instance `=TEXT("07 feb 1985", "dd-mm-yyyy"`, it works! Is there any way around this?

Comment: No. Date values before 1900 can only be stored as text strings (as shown in your screenshot, left aligned by default). Further calculations can only be performed by your own formulas, e. g. with extraction of year values by `VALUE(RIGHT(A3,4))`.

Answer (score 1):

Given that Excel cannot parse the date before `01-01-1900` you'd need a proper date and then select your range, and go `Data`>`Text to Columns`.

Here, select `Delimited` and click `Next`. Deselect all options (usually only `Tab` is selected) and click `Next`. Select `Date` option and choose the format which seems to be `DMY` in your case.

Then you can use the formula such as:

```
=TEXT(A3,"dd-mm-yyyy")
```